# loadStyleDeclarations Never Completes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm calling `loadStyleDeclarations` on a SWF that I've compiled, but it never completes, as in, when I add event listeners the `PROGRESS` event is called but the `COMPLETE` and `ERROR` events are never called. I added a percentage checker to see what's going on, and it gets to 100% and.. just doesn't call the `COMPLETE` event.

```
var dispatcher:* = StyleManager.getStyleManager(null).loadStyleDeclarations(asset, true, true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
dispatcher.addEventListener(StyleEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
dispatcher.addEventListener(StyleEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);
dispatcher.addEventListener(StyleEvent.ERROR, onError);

..

private function onProgress(e:StyleEvent):void
{
    //update progress bar here
    trace(Math.floor(100 * e.bytesLoaded/e.bytesTotal) + "% loaded");
}
private function onComplete(e:StyleEvent):void
{
    trace("Style loaded");
}
private function onError(e:StyleEvent):void
{
    trace("Error loading style");
}
```

Output: (style.swf is the one I'm trying to load)

```
[SWF] C:\Projects\music\bin-debug\Main.swf - 5,656,958 bytes after decompression
0% loaded
83% loaded
100% loaded
[SWF] C:\Projects\music\bin-debug\style.swf - 167,143 bytes after decompression
100% loaded
[SWF] C:\Projects\music\bin-debug\style.swf\[[DYNAMIC]]\1 - 1,223,478 bytes after decompression
[SWF] C:\Projects\music\bin-debug\style.swf\[[DYNAMIC]]\2 - 763,122 bytes after decompression
[SWF] C:\Projects\music\bin-debug\style.swf\[[DYNAMIC]]\3 - 2,083,945 bytes after decompression
```

Any ideas on why the `COMPLETE` event is never firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be in your CSS swf file. I have just checked your code with very basic css (for styling Flex app)

```
s|Application {
backgroundColor: red;
}
```

And your code worked as expected.
Can it be because your CSS is more complex? The output also shows loading some other dynamic stuff from your style.swf

[SWF] C:\Projects\music\bin-debug\style.swf[[DYNAMIC]]\1 - 1,223,478 bytes after decompression
   [SWF] C:\Projects\music\bin-debug\style.swf[[DYNAMIC]]\2 - 763,122 bytes after decompression
   [SWF] C:\Projects\music\bin-debug\style.swf[[DYNAMIC]]\3 - 2,083,945 bytes after decompression

Comment: If the CSS were more complex and had an error in it or something surely at least the ERROR event would have filed? Also.. I'm pretty new to Flash, what does the extra dynamic content mean in terms of loading?

Comment: Does your style.swf contains only style definitions? Or maybe some other things not related to styles?